# Blackberry Connection refused when deploying Phonegap app to device

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-10

)

I want to deploy my app that is created with Phonegap to my BlackBerry Z10 device.

I created some Hello World basic app with Phonegap, then in the terminal (Mac OS Lion) I ran following command:

/Users/macbook/Documents/BB10APP/cordova/run BBZ10

Everythings seems to work fine, but in the end I get a connection error:

[BUILD]   BAR packaging complete
Error: Error: Cannot connect: Connection to https://169.254.x.x:443 refused. Please check IP address settings for the target. You may have to reboot the target.

What could be the problem with the connection?

And is there some other tools that I can use to just send the app via USB to the device like on Android?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution if anyone wants to know:

You have to use the device IP address and not the developer IP that is found in the developer settings on the device (where you see your developer token).

And then it will work (don't ask me what the developer ip is for, just annoying to lead developers in a wrong direction).

The device ip can be found in some settings entry on the device (I don't remember in which unfortunately, but it is there). Just dont use the ip from the developer menu that wont work :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are two IPs in Blackberry

1. IP that is appearing on bottom part of Controller EX. ( 192.168.139.129)
2. IP that is configured in Blackberry simulator (Security and Privacy -> Development Setting)
   EX. ( 169.254.0.1)

Using Controller IP "Network connection problem" issue will be solved

D:\bbndk\hello\platforms\blackberry10\cordova>target.bat add mydevice 192.168.139.129 -t device --password 0000 --pin 00000000